PhpStorm Terminal path
I try to copy paste the files and folder from mini-capstone-vue to mini-capstone.
In mini-capstone I open the terminal and the path is PS C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-capstone-vue>
My ask is why is the terminal navigated to this path C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-capstone-vue> instead of this C:\xampp\htdocs\mini-capstone>
By the way my code editor is PhpStorm.
I super appreciate if you helped me solve this problem.

You would need to illustrate your issue with screenshots in order to provide the additional details/context. Maybe it's how you have your project setup (what folder is that) etc etc.
